# Is \tikzpictextoptions not supposed to contain the text after the quotes only?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    thing/.pic={
        \node {\tikzpictext};
        \node at (0,1) {\tikzpictextoptions};
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic["foo"'bar] {thing};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This renders “foo” as expected, but the node at `(0,1)` shows:

```
every pic quotes/.try,’,bar
```

I expected “'bar”.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Actually, I’m trying to pass 3 arguments to the pic style and according to the manual the quotes functionality should be good for 1 or 2 (to start with).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Well, is the documentation wrong then? It says that it makes `every pic quotes/.try,pic text=<text>, pic text options={<options>}` out of `"<text>"'<options>`. As `pic text` is correctly made available, I assume this long string _is_ executed in the pic “environment”, including `every pic quotes`, but it is not?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It could be a bug in the documentation, even if it isn't a bug in the code. On the other hand, `pic`s are generally buggy and various things don't work as advertised, so a bug in the code wouldn't be surprising either.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat How is the behaviour consistent with what it says about this in the section on `pic`s? The explanation there explicitly rules out the syntax you gave in your first comment. Even read in conjunction with the stuff for `node`s, it isn't possible to make sense of the 'transformation' claim in a way which is consistent with the output. At least, I don't see a way to read that consistent with the output I get.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat But if it was all options, it should include `pic text=foo`, too. In any case, if the second options meant all options, you'd get an infinite regress. If that's really what it means, I'd consider it a documentation bug as it isn't just unclear, but positively misleading.

Comment: @cfr OK, I will remove my comments.... ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It might actually make sense for something more to be added when you use `\tikzpictextoptions`. I wouldn't necessarily expect that to give me just `<options>`, but I'm not sure why it would include `every pic quotes/.try` and `'`. At least the second I'd expect to have been absorbed by the 'transformation'.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I definitely think it is a documentation bug rather than a code bug. `pic text options` clearly is meant to end up getting everything.

Comment: Here's what the transformation string should, I think, say: `pic text={<text>},pic text options={every pic quotes/.try,',<options>}`.

Comment: @cfr I feel it would be rather tough to kick out `every pic quotes/.try` amd `'` from the options. It is simply defined as `\tikzset{pic text options/.store in=\tikzpictextoptions}` in `tikz.code.tex`. So, yes, you can (and perhaps should) read the documentation that way, then it is a documentation bug. (I didn't read it that way, but this is my fault. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think the crucial code is `pic quotes mean={pic text={#1},pic text options={every pic quotes/.try,#2}},` in the quotes library, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I agree it is crucial, but `\tikzset{pic text options/.store in=\tikzpictextoptions}` just means that `pic text options={every pic quotes/.try,#2}}` "forwards" *everything* to the macro `\tikzpictextoptions`, which the OP reads out. So this is all consistent except for the documentation (or some interpretations thereof).

Answer (score 1):

The `'` is a special character that is taken care of by the `quotes` library so that a syntax like

```
"Foo"' Bar
```

is possible without having to do

```
"Foo" {', Bar}
```

which makes it easy to [`swap`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/swap) a node(/label/pin) with one key without having to use `,` and `{}`. The `'` will always be sneaked in with an extra `,`.

On `every pic quotes` being part of the `\pictextoptions`, I'd argue this is an oversight of the manual (where even `'` isn't really transformed in the example). This behaviour is consistent with all other `quotes` cases

- `every pin quotes`,
- `every label quotes` and
- `every edge quotes`.

Where the latter is the only on defined by default with [`auto`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/auto).
This would also be the only one where `'` = `swap` would make sense out of the box unless your pic's node is also along a path segment.

Of course, you can always change the definition of `'` or `swap` inside `every label/pin/pic quotes` so that the shorthand `'` has a more useful meaning when used with labels, pins or a pic's text.